# I changed the domain option in the session_store config, and now previous users can't login or signup without clearing their cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise, subdomain, session-cookies

I have a rails 3.2.8 app that users devise for users_sessions. It previously had a `config/initializers/session_store.rb` file that looked like:

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

The app ran for a while, and users visited the site and signed up. Then I changed     `session_store.rb`

to

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, domain: '.app_name.com'
```

so that session could be persisted across subdomains. The problem that I found was that users who had previously visited the site and signed up can no longer until they clear their cookies. How can I allow previous users to login without requiring them clear their cookies and still allow their session to be persisted across subdomains?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the name of the session cookie it won't delete the old cookie but it will force everyone to get a new one.

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :new_name_store, domain: '.app_name.com'
```